# System booting all right despite wrong root entry in /etc/fstab

Tags: boot, fstab

I have following disk structure:

```
sda1 : Windows
sda2 : an old Linux distribution
sda3 : a new Linux distribution
sda4 : data partition
```

I have grub installed and I choose the system at boot time. I have now been using new Linux distribution only on sda3 and it is working all right. I had been tinkering a little with setting up /etc/fstab file so that it mounts CDROM and data partition at boot time.

I recently saw that the /etc/fstab file in new Linux system (sda3) looks like this:

```
/dev/sda2  /  ext4  errors=remount-ro   0   1  #NOTE THIS ENTRY HAS SDA2!
/dev/sda4  /media/me_user/datapart      ext4      defaults        1      1
/dev/sr0   /media/cdrom0   auto   ro,user,noauto,unhide  0  0
```

It seems that the root entry is wrong: it should have been /dev/sda3  (I must have changed it by mistake). However, the system is working all right and when I boot, the home folder is on sda3 only, not on sda2.

I tried removing the root entry line from /etc/fstab. Then, on booting, I am left on a terminal prompt asking me to login. I can still login but graphics do not start.

I have corrected the fstab file so that root entry is for sda3 but I want to be clear about this issue. Why is my system working all right and I am reaching home folder on sda3 when the root entry in /etc/fstab is for sda2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/fstab` does not directly control which filesystem is mounted as root.  (Which makes sense.  You have to mount a root filesystem before you can read `/etc/fstab`.)

The root filesystem is typically specified in the kernel command line parameters.  If you run `cat /proc/cmdline` to inspect them, you'll probably see `root=/dev/sda3` or `root=UUID=<uuid of /dev/sda3>`.

These parameters are generally configured in the bootloader configuration.  The details here are dependent on the distribution you're using, but assuming you're using grub you'll probably find its config in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.  If this config is correct, then you should end up mounting the right root filesystem.

So why did your boot fail when you removed `/` from `/etc/fstab`?  Part of the system start-up process remounts `/` with the options specified in `/etc/fstab`, and this is probably what failed.

Comment: I do not know the compelling reason for remounting during boot process, but there seems to be a redundancy/duplicacy and hence scope for confusion due to this double specification of root partition.

Comment: Also, why finally correct root partition was being used, even when entry in fstab was incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had similar problem and did some research. My understanding is that it works because you have correct partition set in:

- kernel command line `root=<UUID of />` parameter. Satwell wrote some more about that.
- boot loader settings. For example, assuming `grub` - `gnulinux-simple-<UUID of />` and `--set=root <UUID /boot>` (which may or may not differ from UUID of `/`).

Now, as part of boot process `/etc/fstab` is read and filesystems are mounted (`/` is being remounted writable [`rw`]). For the remount, options from `/etc/fstab` are used. Which, as satwell wrote, possibly explain problems when removing `/` mount line from the file. As for why it works with UUID of wrong partition? Probably because `mount()` syscall, when remounting, ignores the wrong UUID (and uses already established [and correct] one).

From `man 2 mount`:

> **Remounting an existing mount**
>
> The `source` and `filesystemtype` arguments are ignored.